# subscripts dimension and position compared to old style subscripts

Tags: fonts, subscripts, dimensions

Good afternoon. I'n new in LaTex world and I have some trouble with subscripts and superscript dimensions. I have already searched on the web but found nothing that suits my problem. Here is an image of what I get using the following code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
$\textbf{F}_{A\rightarrow B}=k\dfrac{q_{A}q_{B}}{r^{2}}\hat{r}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, subscripts A and B are huge. I could bet that if someone is not familiar with that formula, could mistook the subscripts as product qAqB. Also I notice that the exponent of r, which is 2, is really big.
Since my code is really simple, I cannot spot where the error could be. Just as comparison, here are two pictures of an old LaTex pdf that I have found on the web: the sizes of sub and superscripts here are perfect (and the font is amazing)

[image]
[image]

Maybe it's a problem of just what package I'm using, if that's so I know that I could use for example \usepackage{fouriernc} for a really good old style text and math, but the wrong size of sub and superscripts persists. How can I solve this? (Maybe if you know a text and math package like the second picture, or maybe changing some dimension settings in the fouriernc package).

Here is a picture of what I get using \usepackage{fouriernc} and as you can see the look is better but the problem persists:

[image]

Here is another example of what I get:
[image]
and as you can see the subscripts are too big (look at a_{G} and a_{O})

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

With some minor rewriting it looks better.

```
$\textbf{F}_{A\rightarrow B}=k\frac{\hat{r}}{r^{2}}{q_{A}q_{B}}$
```

[image]

It looks even better without inlining, with formula on display:

```
\documentclass[border=5em,crop=false]{standalone}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}
\kant
\[\textbf{F}_{A\rightarrow B}=k\frac{\hat{r}}{r^{2}}{q_{A}q_{B}}\]
\kant[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Finally, here is the same example after a finely-painful font selection process:

```
\documentclass[border=5em,crop=false]{standalone}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

%% fonts
\usepackage[garamond]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[full]{textcomp}
\usepackage[swashQ]{garamondx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\newcommand{\mathbold}[1]{\ensuremath{\mathbf{#1}}}
\usepackage[supstfm=NewG8-sups]{superiors}
%% microtype
\usepackage[activate={true,nocompatibility},kerning=true,spacing=true,tracking=true,final]{microtype}
\microtypecontext{spacing=nonfrench} %% log said so

\begin{document}
\kant[2]
\[\textbf{F}_{A\rightarrow B}=k\frac{\hat{r}}{r^{2}}{q_{A}q_{B}}\]
\kant[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: With some little improvements it seems to work well. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Use an empty exponent:

```
$\textbf{F}_{A\rightarrow B}=k\dfrac{q_{A}^{}q_{B}^{}}{r^{2}}\hat{r}$
```

[image]

Comment: Well that works quite a little bit but it's just doubling my work everytime I have to write a subscript, and it happens every line actually. But I can't understand: is that a problem of my system or it is like that for everybody? Do you all have these subscripts that to me seem huge?